# Page numbering issue when using package. '1' that cannot be removed on intro pages

Tags: packages, page-numbering

Am using the package **uclathes** ( https://github.com/uclathes/uclathes ) to format my dissertation and to generate the intro pages.

On the 1st, 3rd and 4th pages of the documents (title page, abstract, dissertation committee), I get a '1' that cannot be removed. Perhaps this is a page numbering issue? It is on the bottom of p. 1, on the same line as "University of California, Los Angeles" on p.3, and on the line below "University of California, Los Angeles" on p.4. 
The numbering is otherwise OK (Roman and Arabic numerals used correctly throughout document).

Interestingly, `\usepackage{nopageno}` in the preamble removes all the page numbers throughout the document, except those mysterious '1's.

I've explained my issue on the github page of the package, but alas it does not appear to be maintained.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[PhD,single]{uclathes}
\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\begin{document}

\makeintropages

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

It thinks that the year of your degree is `1` because you've not told it any different. If you tell it differently, it will use the year you tell it. Even if that year is no more likely than the default `1`.

```
\documentclass[PhD,single]{uclathes}
\degreeyear{1066}
\begin{document}

\makeintropages

\end{document}
```

[image: degree of 1066]

In general, you are likely to get bizarre things happening if you fail to provide the information essential for typesetting your thesis in the mandated format - or, at least, the format the class takes to be mandated.

Comment: Thank you! That worked out! I did not realize that this was the information that was missing! I was completely mistaken thinking that it was page numbering.

Comment: The fact that the page had another page number, `2`, and that destroying all page numbering had no effect suggested that numbering was probably not the issue... ;).